# I cannot run my python script in powershell?

Tags: python, powershell

Okay so before I asked this question, I searched for answers through other
 questions. For starters, I am learning python through Learnpythonthehardway.org
now I am learning a lot and already on the fourth example but I need to solve this as its really bothering me.
So when I go to run the file, I type:

```
ex3.py
```

and I get this:

```
ex3.py : The term 'ex3.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,         function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  path  is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ex3.py 
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ex3.py:String) [],    CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So then I check my path and its

```
C:\User\Ally>
```

so I save the file under Ally AND it still doesn't work. I am so done and cannot find a solution. since I need my files to run, I found a temporary method and this is how I run my files,

```
 C:\Python27\EX\ex2.py
```

Powershell can run python by itself and my CMD as well. I change both PATH and PATHTEXT to run Python and .py files.

I do not want to use my temporary fix, I want to find a permanent solution, (A problem should NOT be fixed more than once, if so... it wasn't really fixed)

Comment: If you're saving the files into the current directory, you can't run them just with their name, and need to tell PowerShell that you want to run the file in the current directory by using `.\ ` e.g. `.\ex3.py` - (this is a security thing so someone else can't intercept commands by leaving a script with a common command name lying around and you run it without knowing)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell won't run commands in the current folder by default. Just like on Unix-likes you have to prefix the command with `.\` or `./`, so the following should work:

```
.\ex.py
```

That's assuming Python is installed in a way that you can run commands like that, which must include `.py` in `$Env:PATHEXT` and a file association for `.py` files.

If there is just a file association but `.py` is not in `$Env:PATHEXT` you're going through `ShellExecute` (you can also enforce this with `Invoke-Item`) and thus the interpreter cannot live in the same console as your PowerShell session. The interpreter will run, but in a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run `python ex2.py` instead of just `ex2.py`. There is probably a way to get it to run like that but I don't think that is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

If **ex2.py** is in folder C:\Python27\EX\

The PowerShell session would be

```
PS C:\Python27\> python C:\Python27\EX\ex2.py
```